# Trying to achieve the opacity animation with jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this fiddle made with CSS.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cRU/**

I'm trying to achieve the **exact** animation with jQuery `fadeIn/fadeOut`. (without opacity and animate)

`stop() and finish()` functions used with `fadeIn/fadeOut` are not working because if I move the cursor quickly they simply hide or show the box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `stop()` in your jQuery animation to emulate the CSS animation.

It has the following arguments, `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`, and what you want is to clear the queue, but not jump to the end, so it would be `stop(true, false)`

```
$('.box1').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.box2').stop(true, false).animate({opacity: e.type=='mouseenter'? 1 : 0}, 1500)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q6d57/)

or without the opacity

```
$('.box1').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $('.box2').stop(true, false).fadeToggle(1500)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q6d57/1/)

Comment: @thenewseattle - It's an event handler, triggering on the mouseenter and mouseleave events, and fading the element in and out etc. Look the methods up on the jQuery site if you'd like to know more about how they work, the pertinent part to make it work like your CSS animation is the stop() method.

Comment: It's already there, it's exactly the same as the last one, you just added more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go.

http://jsfiddle.net/defmetalhead/Q5cRU/2/

```
    $(".box1").on({ 
        mouseover: function() {
            $('.box2').stop().fadeIn('slow');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('.box2').stop().fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you move the mouse over and away from it, that animation keeps going.  I think that's what he was trying to avoid.

Comment: didnt specify that. Also, you would just use .stop()

Comment: So, easy fix. IT was not clear. You simply mentioned an issue with stop()

Comment: @DavidAguirre I will be happy if you simply delete this. thanks.